# Nginx redirecting www to no-www (SSL) creates not secure

Tags: nginx, redirect

I am running a Nginx server which serves my website with SSL. For SSL support I do use LetsEncrypte. My Nginx config file in `sites-available` is as shown below:

```
server {
        listen 80;
        server_name domain.nl anotherdomain.nl;
#        return 301 https://$server_name$request_uri;
        return 301 https://domain.nl$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 80;
        server_name www.domain.nl;
        return 301 $scheme://domain.nl$request_uri;
}

server {
        listen 443;

        server_name domain.nl;

        # SSL
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.nl/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.nl/privkey.pem;

        include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

        location / {
                proxy_pass http://localhost:6000;
                proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
                proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
                proxy_set_header Connection 'upgrade';
                proxy_set_header Host $host;
                proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }
}
```

My website works perfectly fine if you visit `domain.nl`. In the first server block I also have another domain, `anotherdomain.nl` in this example. This one also works fine and redirects to the secure website without www. 
Somehow using `www.` before the domain results in the browsers 'Your connection is not sercure' message. I created a new server block for the `www.` and also tried adding it to the first server block. Both didn't work.

I can't see what's wrong with this. Any heads up?

Comment: is you certificate valid for both the domains and the subdomains?

Comment: You don't have www.domain.nl in the https `server` block.

Comment: @MichaelHampton is this required? I just want to redirect it, if possible.

Comment: Of course it's required. How else can you possibly communicate with the browser? It must also be in your certificate.

Comment: Well, since I thought `anotherdomain.nl` did also work with just a redirect I thought `www.` could also work with just a redirect ;)

Answer (score 1):

You need to create another `server` block for the SSL `www.domain.nl` to `domain.nl` rewrite like this:

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name www.domain.nl;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.nl/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/domain.nl/privkey.pem;

    include snippets/ssl-params.conf;

    return 301 https://domain.nl$request_uri;
}
```

You have to also make sure that your certificate is valid for both `www.domain.nl` and `domain.nl`.

Your current configuration causes nginx to process `www.domain.nl` with the default `server` for port 443, because there is no SSL server block with that domain name. If there is a separate `server` block with `default_server` option in `listen` directive, then that is used for the request. If such a server block doesn't exist, then it is processed by the default determined by nginx.